# How does one dynamically add new bindings using Ninject's DI during runtime?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, runtime, mef, ninject

So I'm attempting to use a combination of MEF and Ninject in an application I'm writing.  Basically I'm adding in extensions via MEF during runtime.  I don't understand how (or if it's even possible to) I can update Ninject's bindings during runtime.

For example, say I have the following item imported by MEF:

```
[Export(typeof(ICar))]
public class BmwCar : ICar
{
    private ICarLogger _carLogger;

    public BmwCar(ICarLogger carLogger)
    {
        _carLogger = carLogger;
    }

    public static string Type
    {
        get { return "Sedan"; }
    }

    public string GetBrand()
    {
        return "BMW";
    }

    public static Type InterfaceType { get { return ICar; } }
    public static Type CarType { get { return GetType(); } }
}
```

Now normally if I knew this item at compile time I could just create a Ninject Module with the following bindings like:

```
public class NinjectSetup : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<CarLogFactory>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ICarLogger>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<CarLogFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("vehicleName", BmwCar.Type)).WhenInjectedInto<BmwCar>();
    }
}
```

So the problem is this line:

```
Bind<ICarLogger>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<CarLogFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("vehicleName", BmwCar.Type)).WhenInjectedInto<BmwCar>();
```

I'm not sure how I could add something like that dynamically after BmwCar is imported.  Obviously I can't use the generic at run time since type is needed during compile time.  Because I can't use generics at run time it seems doing something like:

```
var binding = new BindingBuilder<ICarLogger>(new Binding(typeof(ICarLogger)), this.Kernel).ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<CarLogFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("vehicleName", imported.Type)).WhenInjectedInto<imported.CarType>();
```

is not an option.  Anyone aware of away to create new bindings during runtime?

Comment: You don't need to use Bind<>.To's generic parameter - the To method has an overload that accepts a Type as a normal parameter - see my answer.

Comment: Did you mean `return typeof(ICar);` instead of `return ICar;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Bind or Rebind method available on the NInject Kernel.

I don't know anything about MEF, but the code you want might look something like this:

```
void OnApplicationStart()
{
    StaticKernelContainer.Kernel = new StandardKernel(new YourInjectionModule());
}

void AfterMEFHasDoneWhatItNeedsToDo()
{
    // (You may need to use Rebind at this point)
    StaticKernelContainer.Kernel.Bind<ICarLogger>().To(importer.CarType);
}
```

Comment: So I didn't realize it was that simple.  I just used `var bind = new Binding(typeof(BmwCar));` and modified it from there with the overloads.  Once properly set, I just added it the the `Kernel`.  Thanks cbp!

Answer (score 1):

You sure you cant do something cleaner e.g. via [method injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns)?

Also read [the CreateLog example in the contextual binding wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

I'm not convinced you need to go doing stacks of `Bind<>` calls or having to add lots of static helper classes like you have.

Or perhaps I've just read it wrong - can you extend your example a bit; I just dont really get it as-is to be honest?

Comment: Ruben, I'm only using the static helpers for the sake of keeping the ex short. I do believe you have me on the right track, but the problem seems to be with the Bind<>.  With MEF I don't know what the type is going to be until runtime. So I'm not sure how I could bind an interface to an unknown type. For example say I wanted to bind ICar to BmwCar by: `Bind<ICarLogger>().To<BmwCar>().InSingletonScope;` I can't because I don't know what BmwCar is until say someone drops the MEF import library into a watched directory while the main program is running and it then imports the new object BmwCar.

Comment: @j h: `To<T>` requires you to know the static type at compile time. There are two main routes away from this 1) `Bind<I>.To(Type)` when you know the type 2) `Bind<I>.ToMethod( ctx=> CreateMeTheIGivenTheContext(ctx))`. If you take approach 2, you're not managing if and when the bindings get registered which is much poreferable if at all possible IMO. If you're looking to do [multi injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) then you generally do want to have multiple `Bind` calls (possibly making sure to repalce ones if you're watching dirs)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which does not rely on MEF but should do what you want to achieve.

```
// Plugin interface assembly defines
interface ICarInfoProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> CarTypes { get; }
}

// Plugin Bmw Assembly defines
public class BmwPluginCarInfoProvider : ICarInfoProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> CarTypes { 
        get { return new List<string> { "Sedan", "3", "5" }; } 
    }
}

public class BmwPluginModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override Load() {
        // Or use ctor to define car name
        this.Bind<ICarInfoProvider>().To<BmwPluginCarInfoProvider>();
        this.Bind<ICar>().To<BmwCar>().Named("Sedan").OnActivation(car => car.Name = "Sedan");
        this.Bind<ICar>().To<BmwCar>().Named("3").OnActivation(car => car.Name = "3");
        this.Bind<ICar>().To<BmwCar>().Named("5").OnActivation(car => car.Name = "5");
    }
}

// Plugin Toyota Assembly defines
public class ToyotaPluginCarInfoProvider : ICarInfoProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> CarTypes { 
        get { return new List<string> { "Yaris", "Prius", }; } 
    }
}

public class ToyotaPluginModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override Load() {
        // Or use ctor to define car name
        this.Bind<ICarInfoProvider>().To<ToyotaPluginCarInfoProvider>();
        this.Bind<ICar>().To<ToyotaCar>().Named("Yaris").OnActivation(car => car.Name = "Yaris");
        this.Bind<ICar>().To<ToyotaCar>().Named("Prius").OnActivation(car => car.Name = "Prius");
    }
}

// Application
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { 
    // Ensure here that assembly scanning is activated
 });

 public class NinjectSetup : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
            Bind<CarLogFactory>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

            // Sorry for being vague here but I'm in a hurry
            Bind<ICarLogger>().ToMethod(x => x.ContextPreservingGet<CarLogFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("vehicleName", ctx => // access here named parameter or use own parameter to get name //).CreateLogger());
    }
}

// Somewhere in your code

var infos = resolutionRoot.GetAll<ICarInfoProvider>();

// User chooses "Sedan"
var sedan = resolutionRoot.Get<ICar>("Sedan");
```

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that it assumes I know all the data types at runtime.  In my use case, I may have a MEF app running with a directory catalog specified.  Now say someone drops a library that contains `BmwCar` into my 'watched' directory.  MEF would pick that up and import `BmwCar` and I'd like to register bindings based `BmwCar`, but it seems Ninject only allows this through generics unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hy That's not quite correct. I only added the binding for ICar to BmwCar for demo purpose. Bindings for ICarLogger is completly unaware of the actual type. But I see now what you want to achieve. Answer is following.